# Capture return value in sourced logging script

Tags: bash

I source a script to handle two things, capturing standard out/err and return values.  I'm using process substitution:

logger.sh

```
exec > >(
 cat
 echo $?
) 2>&1
```

test.sh

```
. ./logger.sh
ls abc
```

Because I do not have a file called abc, I would like to see this echo the value `1` (from `echo $?`) for the return code.  I'm reading that this will never work with process substitution.  Can this be converted to named pipes?  Will this work?

Run as follows:

```
bash ./test.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing this:

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "DEBUG[$?]" | tee /tmp/log' ERR

xxxx # a non existent command
```

If you already have a `trap`, you can do this :

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'echo "DEBUG[$?]" | tee /tmp/log; do_something_else' ERR 0 1 2 3 15

xxxx # a non existent command
```

Comment: Nice, that does work... I can put that in `logger.sh` .. What if the sourcing script `test.sh` has a trap in it though?  I don't want to break it...

Comment: To clarify, I used `trap '....' EXIT` to catch both error and success.  Also, the trap goes in `logger.sh` after the exec block is closed.